# JMenu not in Windows look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Hi I've got a little Swing Application with a Menu.
First two attributes containing the menues text are created, then the lookandfeel is set to windows and at last the menues are filled. 
Here is the source code:

```
private JMenu[] Menue={new JMenu("File")};

private JMenuItem[][] MenuItemsString ={{new JMenuItem("Import"),new JMenuItem("Export")}};
...
public window(){
       super ("Q3MeshConverter");

       plate = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       try{
           UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");// set Windows lookandfeel
           }
           catch(Exception x){

           }
       menuBar = new JMenuBar();
       ...
       setJMenuBar(menuBar);

       JMenu[] Menu =Menue;
       JMenuItem[][] MenuItems =MenuItemsString;
       for(int m=0;m<Menu.length;m++){// loop trough the Menu(es)
           menuBar.add(Menu[m]);
           for(int mi=0;mi<MenuItems[m].length;mi++){// loop through the MenuItems
               Menu[m].add(MenuItems[m][mi]);
               MenuItems[m][mi].addActionListener(this);
           }
       }
       ...   
       setContentPane (plate);
}
```

And that's the ugly output:
[image]

Why does it looks like this?

Comment: Have you tried checking the exception instead of ignoring it to make sure the l&f has actually been changed: `catch(Exception x){ System.out.println("Could not change the look and feel");}`

Comment: Thank you, but I've checked it now and there were no Exception.

Comment: If you change the `setLookAndFeel(...)` to `setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())` anything changes?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the look and feel in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest approach to the problem; just put it before any code inside the main method.

Answer (score 8):

There is no magic how a component created before the LAF change can know about it, you have to tell it :-)

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(someComponent);
```